# Cannot call DELETE webapi method due to 405 Http status code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written API with .NET Core 3.0 Preview, and using Angular 8 for frontend.
I have one method on User controller called DeleteUser. This is the method:

```
//DELETE users/d18da620-6e4d-4b1c-a1ec-36d89145f4ca
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUser(Guid id) {
    ...
}
```

So, when request is performed with Angular like this:

```
this.usersApiService.deleteUser(userId).subscribe((data) => {
    ...
}
```

After this call is performed, I get following output in Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService:Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware:Information: Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
```

However, I've set custom CORS policy. In `ConfigureServices` I have this:

```
services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
            .AllowAnyHeader());
});
```

and in Configure method, I use this policy:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

So my question is, how to successfuly call this delete method? What am I missing?

Edit: This is my deleteUser method that calls api

```
public deleteUser(userId) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
      }),
      body: {
        id: userId
      }
    };
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.USERSENDPOINT, httpOptions);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `usersApiService.deleteUser` code?

Comment: @Nikita, oh yeah, I pasted wrong code there :) Thank you. Will add it to my question

Comment: By spec, you can't have a body in a DELETE call. The URL has to define the resource to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
Try to call your method in angular like this:

> this.httpClient.delete(this.USERSENDPOINT+"/"+userId);

hope it helps

Comment: With this configuration, I get following error: `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The configuration section 'httpProtocol' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration`

Comment: Nah, It wasnt inside `system.webServer element`. However, with this added to web.config, now I can't event perform basic Get on whole collection (example: `GET /users`

Comment: There is a error in JS console saying that CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Origin does not match localhost:4200

Comment: Where is the body in your delete request?

Comment: I believe that problem is in Angular not in .NET ... just occurred to me this now.

Comment: Can send your angular request with out header?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198409/discussion-between-golobich-and-ehsan-kiani).